# Is it possible to customize Chrome to hide Gtalk's chat prompt

Tags: google-chrome

Is it possible to hide alerts shown at Chrome browser

Kindly have a look at the below screen cut :

[image]

Scenario :

I used to hangout/chat with my friends through Google chat box(hangout screen). Whenever there is an message chrome pops up with alert at the tab like e.g "john says".

Is it possible to disable alerts on Chrome?

in gtalk we could disable notifications, but I need this for Google chrome, any thoughts to switch off this kind of alerts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote up a [bookmarklet to handle the blinking notifications](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2014/07/stoptabalerts-bookmarklet-to-replace.html). Drag and drop the bookmarklet to the Bookmarks Bar (in Chrome or Bookmarks Toolbar in Firefox or the equivalent in any other browser). Click on the bookmarklet while you're on the Gmail tab and it will override the blinking messages with the custom text 'Advanced Rocket Engineering' (or anything else you like)

It is not extensively tested. I only did some basic testing in Chrome and it worked.